# StackLayout and its contents not showing inside a collectionview if maximizes the windows it appears in UWP with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

collectionview contains a label and StackLayout and its contents. The label is showing but StackLayout contents not showing and only if maximizes the windows it appears in UWP.this strange behaviour only occurring in uwp, not happening with ios or android. used xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2337

```
<CollectionView 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="20,0" 
                   RowDefinitions="auto,auto">
                           <Label Text="DateTime" IsVisible="{Binding IsDateVisible}" />
                            <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             IsVisible="{Binding IsDateVisible}">
                            <DatePicker Date="{Binding DateValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               Format="MMMM dd, yy"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               MaximumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
                                />
                            <TimePicker Time="{Binding TimeValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsDateVisible}"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           </CollectionView>
```

Comment: It looks know [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9102)about CollectionView, please vote up this report, and currently the workaround is use listview to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StackLayout and its contents not showing inside a collectionview if maximizes the windows it appears in UWP with Xamarin.Forms

It looks know [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9102) for `CollectionView`, please vote up this report and Keep an eye on the following update, currently the workaround is use `listview` to replace.

```
<ListView  SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="20,0" RowDefinitions="auto,auto">
                    <Label IsVisible="true" Text="DateTime" />
                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        IsVisible="true"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <DatePicker
                            Format="MMMM dd, yy"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            MaximumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" />
                        <TimePicker HorizontalOptions="Start" IsVisible="true" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```